# Windows 7 installation - CD\DVD driver issue on laptop

Tags: windows-7, drivers, installation, optical-drive

I'm installing Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit from an MSDN download onto a new Dell Studio 1558 laptop.
Right after clicking "Install Now" I get the following message in a window titled ***Load Driver***:

> A required CD/DVD drive device driver
>   is missing. If you have a driver
>   floppy disk, CD, DVD, or USB flash
>   drive, please insert it now.

I went to Dell support and tried to download a driver, but all I found was a firmware upgrade executable for DOS and for Windows.

How can I overcome this problem? I'm not even sure which driver model I have inside the laptop...

Comment: I highly doubt your Dell Studio has a DVD drive that needs a special driver. 

I would try to confirm that your copy of Windows 7 was downloaded without error and then try to install off a Flash Drive if you have one with at least 4GB. 

Then follow a guide like this: http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/

Comment: I had this happen on an old (circa 2003) Tyan dual Xeon board and ended up just having to install from USB key.  Never could figure the damned thing out. :/

Comment: @wag2639 - you were right - indeed it was a download error. Thanks for the guide, it helped me anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this before, most of the time it is a corrupt download or corrupt burn job, retry the download and burn it at a slow speed.

If this does not work the suggestion by Shinrai will get it installed. (Install from USB drive)

Comment: It was indeed a corrupt download. A sha1 check confirmed it.