# esys NoteBook SZ900P - Unable to load drivers during Windows 7 Setup through USB boot?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, setup

I have esys Notebook SZ900P, which was came with preloaded Ubuntu. Now i need to work on Windows so i am trying to install `Windows 7` from USB Pen Drive but it prompt me to `Load Drivers for CD/DVD drive device drivers`

It is showing following message:

> A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing. If you have a driver floppy disk, CD, >DVD, or USB flash drive, please insert it now.
>       ......
>   ...

I am looking for it's ACHI Serial ATA drivers,It is upgraded hardware so windows 7 is not loading drivers for it.

Can anyone suggest me drivers for this laptop or download link for serial ata drivers for various Intel Chip set. I have searched alot for getting drivers and solution for it, but fails to get any.. Hope someone have some idea about these, so i thought to ask here to my other mates.

Please do not suggest [this](https://superuser.com/questions/204198/windows-7-installation-cd-dvd-driver-issue-on-laptop) to me..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It looks like a standard netbook. Could you add the output of lshw to your question? It would help determining what drivers exactly are needed.

Comment: dear.. i am not able to get hardware information of this laptop right now.. operating system is not running right now.